# Isset and empty array best practice

Tags: php

I'm asking what's the best way to check if an array contain a non-empty value:

```
if(isset($parameters["index"]) && !empty($parameter["index"]))
```

vs

```
if(false === empty($parameter["index"]))
```

I think 1 and 2 are similar ? And wish is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Empty: Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals false. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

You can safely go:

```
if( !empty($parameter["index"]) ) { ... }
```

Beyond that, PHP 7.0 added the `??` operator which lets you work with possibly undefined things a little more nicely.

Assuming you're going to be using `$parameter["index"]` more than once, it's often good practice to store the lookup to a variable rather than referencing it more than once.

This helps prevent human errors that come from for instance misspelling the key.

```
$paramIndex = $parameter["index"] ?? null;
if( $paramIndex ) { ... }
```